# MAMP - Got bad request after clicking on Start Servers

Tags: mamp

After installing MAMP 4.0 for mac. I click on "Start Servers", then chrome shows a page (http://localhost:8888/MAMP/) with (Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.) The same thing when I click on "Open WebStart Page".